# multi-touch distance detection limitation

Tags: android, canvas, multi-touch, touch-event

I work with simple code with multi-touch capabilities

- the app in some cases requires the distance between the pointers to be close to each other
- If (pointer 1) close to (pointer 2) then the device will consider them as one pointer

Is that a hardware or a software limitation?

any suggestion to how to deal with that ?

Comment: I think that it is at least system-level definition.

Comment: @VladMatvienko do you recommend any API Guides to read from ?

Comment: I don't think you can do it without root at least.

Answer (score 0):

there's a matrix solution that I tried 
(by setting the scale less than 1 by a little

```
    matrix.setScale(.95,.95,/*center pivot (by "Computing the center bounds of the control points")*/,/*center pivot*/);
```

the bounds in my case is the path of the canvas

"calculating the center is important to make the new points between the old points - look at the img -

then transform the points by the matrix

this will give me an acceptable solution but not accurate

[Temp-solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tpcr.png)